# Start a background process on remote machine using python

Tags: python, ssh, cpu-usage, fabric

I am running a python script which involves running a "burnP6" background process on a remote machine.

I tried to use fabric:

```
import fabric.api
fabric.api.execute(run_burnP6_bg, hosts=[remote_machine])

def run_burnP6_bg():
    fabric.api.run("burnP6 &")
```

Also I tried using ssh -f with subprocess:

```
import subprocess

def cpu_load(receiver, load_percent='100', time_seconds='3'):
    if 1<= load_percent and 100 >= load_percent:
        cmd = 'ssh -f xyz@{1} '.format(ip_addr) + "'burnP6 &'"
        subprocess.call(cmd.split(' '))
    elif 0 == load_percent:
        # No load to be added
        pass
```

But both of them did not work. On running top in the remote server I did not see any burnP6 process.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: try `fabric.api.run("(nohup burnP6 &)")` . For supbrocess  use `shlex.split()` rather than `str.split()`. I suspect your 'command' is not parsed as expected. Use `-l user` rather than `@`. Use 'disown -a` and `nohup` to keep process running even after terminal it uses is closed. In general, test your ssh command first, before you try to push it into python/fabric.

Comment: Thanks. The error was in splitting. I needed my cmd list to be in form :  ['ssh', '-f', 'acelio', 'nohup burnP6 &']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login with ssh and start any job process with `job&`. Login with ssh in a different window and do `ps` to check for your job: you should see it running. Now logout of your first ssh and check again for your job process. You will notice that it is now gone. This happens because jobs are attached to a terminal by default and are sent a SIGHUP when the terminal is closed.

Now repeat the process with running `nohup job&` or `disown job&`. These both prevent the SIGHUP from killing the job process.

To fix your code you can use either of the following:

```
import fabric.api
fabric.api.execute(run_burnP6_bg, hosts=[remote_machine])

def run_burnP6_bg():
    fabric.api.run("nohup burnP6 &")
```

or with subprocess

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'ssh -f xyz@{1} '.format(ip_addr) + "'nohup burnP6 &'"
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

these should prevent your job from dying when the ssh session ends.

Comment: I think using split would be wrong as I noted in the comment for question. But yes otherwise with fabric, it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sorry for second example not working. I'll edit.

Comment: this really doesn't work, you should at least use `pty=false`